# trying to add to cart in woocommerce for product with variations

Tags: woocommerce

I'm trying to create a link to add a product with variations directly to the car but it's not working. ANy ideas what to use?
https://www.mysite.com/cart/?add-to-cart=2854&variation_id=2857

Comment: Take a look at this article by Remi Corson: http://www.remicorson.com/?s=add+variation+to+cart

Comment: funnily enough that was the example I looked at. I added an attribute called Duration but when I do: ttps://www.mysite.com/cart/?add-to-cart=2854&variation_id=2857&attribute_pa_Duration=7   nothing happens

Comment: You sure your slug is right? Normally they are lowercase (I think always, in fact). Try: `attribute_pa_dura‌​tion' maybe or whatever the slug is for the attribute.